# Liner Interpolation Of FORCE at some Strain Value in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a Abaqus Script in Python.I have the Experimental data of Strains and Forces. I then calculated strains and Forces from Simulation. Now I want to Interpolate Force in Experiments at Strain value obtained from Simulation. So that later I can calculate the error between force in Simlulation and force in Experiments. My code should search the Strain value in Simulation from my given Experimental Data and then give me interpolated values of Force in experiments.

Eg :- These are values of Force and Strain from Simulation

```
Strain_sim = [0.00000,0.00372,0.007455,0.013042,0.021426,0.03400,0.0372636]
Force_sim  = [0.0000, 73.0884,146.1769,255.8095,420.2585,666.9319,730.8843]
```

i have a lot of values from Experiments jus as eg.

```
Strain_Experiments = [0.003723102 , 0.003730732 , _ , ..... ]
Forces_Experiments = [605.96676 , 607.00794  , _ , ..... ]
```

for Strain 0.00372 the Force value will be

```
Linear_Interpolation = (0.00372-0.003723102)*(607.00794 - 605.96676) / ( 0.003730732 -0.003723102) + 605.96676
Interpolation = 606.41229
```

The thing is that I have Strain values from Simulation that are not in My experimental data so how can i Interpolate the forces at strain values that are not in my experimental data ?
Hope I explained the problem well

Thank You

Comment: You could look into [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)

Comment: The more correct way to say it is "strain (tensor) is a function of stress (tensor)" and "stress (tensor) is a function of force (vector)".  You're making an implicity assumption about the stress-force relationship when you do this.  Any linear interpolation scheme (Lagrangian shape functions) ought to do fine.

Comment: My Abaqus cannot use scipy or numpy modules. Can you explain the Code in Detail.